# iterate through properties of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, iteration

I am working on a filter engine for my app. Right now, I am having issues with the iteration between an object data which I need to check against the array of filters the user applies. The final goal is to return the object(s) that match one or multiple filter choices.

Here is my code:

```
const Results = () => {
const [dataStored, setDataStored] = useState([])
const filterArray = useSelector(state => state.filterArray);
const doctors = useSelector(state => state.doctors);

// let doctorsResult = doctors.map(doctor => doctor.indexOf(filterArray) !== -1 )

// let doctorsResult = doctors.map(doctor => {for(let key of Object.keys(doctor)){
//     if (key === 'price' || key === 'gender' || key === 'language'){
//     // setDataStored([...dataStored, doctor[key]])
//     console.log("dataStored",doctor[key])}
//     //  return (dataStored.indexOf(filterArray) !== -1 )

// }})

let doctorsResult = doctors.map(doctor => {
    Object.keys(doctor).forEach((key) => {
        if (key === 'price' || key === 'gender' || key === 'language') {
            setDataStored([...dataStored, doctor[key]])
            console.log("dataStored", dataStored)
        }
        return (dataStored.indexOf(filterArray) !== -1)
    })
})
```

Each object has multiple properties, but I only need to check the 'price, gender, and language' values. Properties are not equal, some are just a string, others are an array. So far, I have been able to do the iteration through the properties using for..in and forEach loops. My issue is, I am not able to compare and return any data because it is not an array, therefore, indexOf() gives me an error. When I try `setDataStored([...dataStored, doctor[key]])`, the State goes into infinite loop.

I am fairly new to all this. If someone has a better way to achieve this, I will really appreciate it.

Edit:

Here is the shape of filterArray
It's a dynamic filter, starts empty and then gets populated

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Are you looking for `filter` instead of `map`? Also, for that `dataStored` you probably just want to initialise that before your loop and then `push` to it. Do not use a state hook for this.

Comment: What is the shape of `filterArray`?

Comment: @Bergi is spot on. During one render, you're calling `setDataStored` n times, where n is the number of matches. The problem is, each time after the first you're calling setDataStored with stale data. This means that each render is only adding *one* item to dataStored, despite doing all that work. As a general rule, if you're computing state in your component with useState, you want to do the computation in a memo or effect hook.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, you were spot on. Your comment did help me to achieve what I was trying to do. Thanks to the rest of the comments, I realized I need to apply a filter function too, so I can return an array of the objects that return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to get the state from two selectors and do some work, then return the result? This is the perfect type of problem for `reselect`. Reselect is a helper that allows you to memoize expensive calculations regarding state selectors.

https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Heres what that could look like for you.

`$ yarn add reselect`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const filterArraySelector = (state) => state.filterArray;
const doctorsSelector = (state) => state.doctors;

const filteredDoctorsSelector = createSelector(doctorsSelector, filterArraySelector, (filterArray, doctors) => {
  return doctors.filter((doctor) => {
    return filterArray.all((key) => {
      // Do some comparison here, return true if you want to include the doctor in the results
      return doctor[key] !== undefined;
    });
  });
});

const Results = () => {
  const filteredDoctors = useSelector(filteredDoctorsSelector);

  return filteredDoctors.map((doctor) => <span>{doctor}</span>);
};
```

#### Alternative Option

Instead of using `createSelector` to memoize the filtering, you can simply filter the doctors every time you render. Like this:

```js
const Results = () => {
  const filterArray = useSelector((state) => state.filterArray);
  const doctors = useSelector((state) => state.doctors);

  const filteredDoctors = useMemo(
    () =>
      doctors.filter((doctor) => {
        return filterArray.all((key) => {
          // Do some comparison here, return true if you want to return the doctor
          return doctor[key] !== undefined;
        });
      }),
    [doctors, filterArray]
  );

  return filteredDoctors.map((doctor) => <span>{doctor}</span>);
};
```

#### Update:

Given a filterArray of values like this:

```js
const filterArray = ['Female', 'English'];
```

We can update the filter function to test the Objects values against the filterArray values. If any of the attribute values match the filterArray values, then we can include the doctor in the resulting filteredDoctors list.

```js
const Results = () => {
  const filterArray = useSelector((state) => state.filterArray);
  const doctors = useSelector((state) => state.doctors);

  const filteredDoctors = useMemo(() => {
    return doctors.filter((doctor) => {
      return filterArray.some((filter) => {
        return Object.values(doctor).some((value) => value === filter);
      });
    });
  }, [doctors, filterArray]);

  return filteredDoctors.map((doctor) => <span>{doctor}</span>);
};
```

#### Update:

After discussion in chat:

```js
const Results = () => {
  const filterArray = useSelector((state) => state.filterArray);
  const doctors = useSelector((state) => state.doctors);

  const filteredDoctors = useMemo(() => {
    return doctors.filter((doctor) => {
      return filterArray.some((filter) => {
        return Object.values(doctor).some((value) => {
          // If the attribute value is an array
          if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return value.some((value) => value === filter);
          }
          // If the attribute value is an object, get the values from the object
          if (typeof value === 'object') {
            return Object.values(value).some((value) => value === filter);
          }
          // By default, expect the value to be a string
          return value === filter;
        });
      });
    });
  }, [doctors, filterArray]);

  return filteredDoctors.map((doctor) => <span>{doctor}</span>);
};
```

Comment: I'd recommend using useMemo for the alternate case instead of recalculating on every render. I love our shiny new react toys. Excellent answer regardless.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells that is an excellent suggestion, I will update my code snippet.

Comment: Shouldn't [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/all) be [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)? *"The final goal is to return the object(s) that match one or multiple filter choices."* eg. `filterArray.some(key => doctor[key] !== undefined)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I'm learning new stuff here. What would be the main difference between useMemo or reSelect? What it comes at the top of my mind, reSelect will stop only when both useSelectors have been completely compared, while useMemo can be set to trigger any time during the filtering. Is that right?

Comment: @3limin4t0r probably, it wasn't clear to me what the shape of filterArray was, or what the logic for filtering would be.

Comment: @JonathanSandler `useMemo` and `createSelector` work pretty much the same way in this case. They both memoize the results of calling a function, and they will return the same result unless the dependencies change. In both cases the dependencies and the results are the same. The difference is that `useMemo` is a native function in React, and `createSelector` is a function from the `reselect` library.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated the post with a screenshot of filterArrays. It's a dynamic array that gets populated. It starts empty. The filtering would be, if filterArray is empty, it will return all the objects, if it finds objects that their properties values match the filterArray, then it returns only those objects instead. Is that what you guys where asking?

Comment: @JonathanSandler, I've updated my answer to filter the doctors by matching the attribute values against the filterArray values you provided in your screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224105/discussion-between-jonathan-sandler-and-benjamin).